# Image processing: pointer becomes nullptr without resetting it

Tags: c++, c++-cli, clr, managed-c++

I am working on a project which recovers an image line by line and has to recolor any objects that are inside the image. Our image is gathered in real time and we receive a 1D `byte[]` array on each call. Placing each 1D array on top of each other reconstructs the 2D image. This program has a buffer of 300 arrays which is large enough to display each object.

The data inside the array is a numeric value corresponding to a color. Objects often have several colors and this code has to recolor each object with the most present color.

Initially, this code was written in C#, but I had several performance issues so this program was adapted to a CLI/CLR project with C++ to have access to pointers which would hugely improve speed.

For each pixel in the array, I instanciate a *Product* class which contains data about the current pixel. Each *Product* class contains a pointer to a *Info* class containing data about the current object. The program looks at previous adjacent pixels and determines if the pixel belongs to the same object. If so, the *Info* pointer in the *Product* class of the current pixel will point to the *Info* class of the previous pixel. In this way, when counting each color of the whole object, I only have to update the most present color index in the *Info* class to update the color of each pixel, and thus recolor the whole object.

Here is the main code with the loop:

```
    void ProductsClipping::ProcessClippingFrame(array<unsigned char>^% CurrentProcessingFrame) {
        Monitor::Enter(obj);
        try {
            // Update Current Buffer Index
            BufferIndex++;
            if (BufferIndex >= BufferSize) BufferIndex = 0;

            // Get Current Frame
            CurrentProductFrame = ProductResult[BufferIndex];

            // Update Result Buffer Index
            ResultBufferIndex++;
            if (ResultBufferIndex >= BufferSize) ResultBufferIndex = 0;

            // Get Result Frame
            ResultFrame = ProductResult[ResultBufferIndex];

            // Process each pixel
            for (int i = 0; i < PixelsCount; i++) {
                Product^ LastProduct = LastProductFrame[i];

                if (LastProduct != nullptr && LastProduct->ProductInfo != nullptr && LastProduct->ProductInfo->BufferIndex != BufferIndex) {
                    LastProduct->ProductInfo->Height++;
                    LastProduct->ProductInfo->BufferIndex = BufferIndex;
                    LastProduct->ProductInfo->isResetMax = true;
                    LastProduct->ProductInfo->isActive = false;
                    LastProduct->UpdateProductIndex();
                }

                // If product in this pixel 
                if (CurrentProcessingFrame[i] > 0) {
                    bool hasParent = false;

                    // If last pixel don't belong to this product
                    if (CurrentProductFrame[i] == nullptr) CurrentProductFrame[i] = gcnew Product;
                    Product^ CurrentProduct = CurrentProductFrame[i];

                    // Check if has a particle in above pixel
                    if (LastProduct != nullptr && LastProduct->ProductID > 0) {
                        CurrentProduct->Update_Info(LastProduct->ProductInfo, LastProduct->ProductID, false);
                        hasParent = true;
                    }
                    Product^ PreviousProduct = i > 0 ? CurrentProductFrame[i - 1] : nullptr;

                    // Check if is a particle in the left of the pixel
                    if (PreviousProduct != nullptr && PreviousProduct->ProductID > 0) {
                        // If has particle above and in the left of pixel and the two particle is not the same
                        if (hasParent) {
                            if (PreviousProduct->ProductID != CurrentProduct->ProductID) {
                                PreviousProduct->Update_Info(CurrentProduct->ProductInfo, CurrentProduct->ProductID, true);
                            }
                        } else {
                            CurrentProduct->Update_Info(PreviousProduct->ProductInfo, PreviousProduct->ProductID, false);
                            hasParent = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!hasParent) {
                        if (i + 1 < CurrentProcessingFrame->Length && CurrentProcessingFrame[i + 1] > 0) {
                            CurrentProductFrame[i + 1] = CurrentProduct;

                            // End of product
                            if (LastProduct != nullptr && LastProduct->IsEndOfProduct && i == LastProduct->ProductInfo->LastMax) {
                                LastProduct->Close();
                            }
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            CurrentProduct->ProductID = ProductID;
                            ProductID++;
                        }
                    }

                    // If first pixel of product. Initialize information data
                    if (CurrentProduct->ProductInfo == nullptr) {
                        CurrentProduct->Initialize_Info(gcnew Info());
                        CurrentProduct->ProductInfo->ID = CurrentProduct->ProductID;
                        CurrentProduct->ProductInfo->BufferIndex = BufferIndex;
                    }
                    CurrentProduct->ProductInfo->LastMax = (CurrentProduct->ProductInfo->isResetMax) ? i : Math::Max(i, CurrentProduct->ProductInfo->LastMax);
                }

                // If End of product
                if (LastProduct != nullptr && LastProduct->IsEndOfProduct && i == LastProduct->ProductInfo->LastMax) LastProduct->Close();
                ResultFrame[i] = nullptr;
            }
            LastProductFrame = CurrentProductFrame;
        } finally { Monitor::Exit(obj); }
    }
```

This is the code of the *Product* class with the *Info* pointer.

```
ref class Product {
    private:
        Info^ *_ProductInfo = nullptr;

    public:
        unsigned int ProductID;
        property Info^ ProductInfo {
            Info^ get() {
                if (!_ProductInfo) return nullptr;
                return *_ProductInfo;
            }
        }

        property bool IsEndOfProduct {
            bool get() { return ProductInfo != nullptr && ProductInfo->isOpen && !ProductInfo->isActive; }
        }

        void Update_Info(Info^ NewInfo, unsigned int NewProductID, bool isBelongOtherProduct) {
            if (NewInfo != nullptr) NewInfo->isActive = true;
            ProductID = NewProductID;
            _ProductInfo = &NewInfo;
        }

        void Initialize_Info(Info^ NewInfo) {
            _ProductInfo = &NewInfo;
        }

        void Close() {
            ProductInfo->isOpen = false;
        }
};
```

The issue I experience is that for the first pixel in the object, the pointer points correctly towards the *Info* class, but on the next iteration, when wanting to set the next pixel to the same *Info* class, the first pointer becomes nullptr

**EDIT:** Added test code calling the loop:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    byte[][] Frame = new byte[][]
    {
                new byte[]{ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                new byte[]{ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                new byte[]{ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
                new byte[]{ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                new byte[]{ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                new byte[]{ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
                new byte[]{ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                new byte[]{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
                new byte[]{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                new byte[]{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                new byte[]{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                new byte[]{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };

    ProductsClipping ClippingFrame;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int NbArrays = Frame.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < NbArrays; i++)
        {
            ClippingFrame.ProcessClippingFrame(ref Frame[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `Info^ *_ProductInfo`? `Info^` already behaves like a pointer... I feel like somewhere in your mixing of CLR handles and C++ pointers you are violating the [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and are left with UB (in the form of a dead object being dereferenced).

Comment: Often such things are a result of some other wayward pointer going beyond its bounds or the like. What happens when you step through in the debugger with a watch on that variable? When does it change? Can you put a data breakpoint on that location when it changes (I can't remember if C++/CLR supports that feature or not)? If all else fails, divide and conquer: start by commenting out half the code, and run it. If the problem still happens, do it again. If not, comment out the other half. Keep doing this as much as you are able until you can find the culprit.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, True. However they do not act the same. For instance, if I declare the following: _Info_ I1; _Info_ I2 = I1; and _Info_ I3; I1 = I3. In this case I2 and I3 will not have the same reference.

Comment: @metal At the end of the loop, in LastProductFrame, I have all the _Product_ objects containing pointers to the same _Info_ class. When this function is called again (next frame), with a breakpoint at the first line, I can see the content of LastProductFrame and see that only the first _Product_ object in this array has a nullptr. All the other _Product_ objects in this array still have a correct pointer.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying all looks good when leaving the first call of the given function but isn't when it is called the next time. That would suggest the thing overwriting it might lie outside this function. So do we need to see the code for the function(s) calling this function?

Comment: Our test code (in which this issue appears), calls this function in a simple method containing a for loop iterating through a hand made 2D `byte[10][10]`. I'll update the question to add this info.